# ¿Qué tipo de problemas resuelve la programación funcional de mejor manera que los otros paradigmas?

Tags: programación-funcional, lambda

La información que hay sobre **programación funcional**, se remite mayormente a los lenguajes, con muy poca amplitud de la programación funcional
en sí misma como una forma pensar para modelar la solución de los problemas.

Al aprender POO, desde un inicio se nos deja claro que el *problema de modelar* los sistemas
del mundo real a través de sus objetos será más intuitivo, y esto hará que el código esté directamente relacionado a los
objetos implicados en la tarea, con lo cual será fácil su documentación, etc. Pero en cuanto a la **programación funcional**, la generalidad de sus promotores, de inicio nos dicen que será algo difícil pero que en un tiempo valdrá la pena, *el código será más legible*, pero aún eso me parece una
petición de fé en lugar de algo concreto.

Por ejemplo, la programación funcional de inicio me pareció conveniente en:

- *Selección de registros*, las instrucciones *lambda* en c++ moderno pueden hacer con
  una línea para lo que normalmente se requerirían bucles.

Por otro lado, me parece que en otro tipo de problemas puede ser más conveniente la POO:

- *Modelado de objetos*, digamos para simular un microprocesador puedo plantear los objetos y las relaciones entre estos, observando microprocesadores reales.

Entonces nos serviría mucho saber **¿Qué otros tipos de problemas dentro la programación ya se sabe que son más convenientes para ser resueltos con la programación funcional?** (y esto debería estar de inicio en cada documento, así como hicieron con la POO). Digamos arbitrariamente otros problemas como:

- Análisis sintáctico, ...
- Programación de intérpretes, ...
- Respuesta en tiempo real, ...
- Modelado de alguna técnica de inteligencia artificial, ...
- Etc. Etc. Etc.

¿Se sabe que en algunos de estos u otros campos la programación funcional claramente facilita nuestro trabajo?

Quisiera dejar claro que no me estoy refiriendo a los lenguajes de programación,
pues hoy en día son multiparadigma, sino a cómo pensamos funcionalmente.

Gracias anteladas.

Comment: ¿Qué problemas resuelve mejor con respecto a qué? ¿A mi opinión?

Comment: Problemas computacionales, por ejemplo se me ocurre que la programación funcional es ventajosa en selección de registros. Pero no me parece que tenga ventajas al modelar objetos del mundo real, por ejemplo al modelar un microprocesador para emular su funcionamiento, ahí me parece que la POO tiene ventajas. Pero eso es justo lo que estoy preguntando.
Si este aspecto es muy confuso, puedo editar mi pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Como bien comentas, la programación funcional y la programación declarativa llevan muchos años entre nosotros, pero es últimamente cuando se está poniendo más de moda: por ejemplo, Java y C# han añadido en los últimos años las funciones lambda a su sintaxis y lenguajes como Groovy o Scala nacieron con esa idea como principio.

Las ventajas principales son dos:

- La programación declarativa suele permitir un código más sencillo de entender a quien lo lee, porque se centra más en qué se quiere hacer que en el cómo, intentando abstraerse de las limitaciones del hardware a la hora de realizar operaciones.
- Al usar lambdas y recursividad, generalmente no hace falta definir variables porque simplemente tomamos los parámetros de entrada y devolvemos una operación como salida. Por tanto trabajamos con inmutables.

Esta segunda característica pasaba más desapercibida antes, pero es muy importante hoy día por un cambio de paradigma en el hardware: las CPU multi núcleo. Al no haber dependencias, el código funcional tiende a ser más paralelizable que el código imperativo clásico.

¿Qué tipo de problemas se resuelven mejor? Realmente ya entramos en un campo subjetivo: Cualquier problema que resuelvas mediante programación funcional, se puede resolver con programación imperativa con la misma eficiencia. Si lo piensas bien, no hay lenguaje más imperativo que el lenguaje máquina, que es el único que entiende una computadora. Y cualquier programa escrito con un lenguaje funcional será traducido y ejecutado en lenguaje máquina.

Por tanto podemos pensar en "mejor" sólo en términos de brevedad o claridad del código, que sea más intuitivo y legible. Pero un programador experimentado en C (por poner un ejemplo) considerará más legible una solución a un problema que esté escrita en C que en un lenguaje que no domina.

Comment: La programación puamente funcional y la programación puramente declarativa no se parecen en lo más mínimo, por favor elimina las referencias a la pogramación declarativa en tu respuesta parra evitar confusiones a quienes lean esto en un futuro.

Comment: La programación funcional es un subconjunto de la programación declarativa, por ejemplo Haskell es un lenguaje puramente declarativo y funcional. Hay lenguajes declarativos no funcionales, como Prolog, pero decir que no se parecen no es correcto. Puedes leer una respuesta en SO [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925689/functional-programming-vs-declarative-programming-vs-imperative-programming)